# Warning: passing argument 4 of 'fread' from incompatible pointer type in C?

Tags: c, warnings

hey I want to read the data from a ppm file but I've a little problem with my code: fread(ptr,width*height,1,data); gives me a warning with ,,passing argument 4 of 'fread' from incompatible pointer type" doeas anyone know how to fix this?

````
```
FILE *ptr;
int width, height, max_colour;
ptr = fopen("picture.ppm","rb"); 

fscanf (ptr, "P3\n %d\n %d\n %d", &width, &height, &max_colour);
printf("%d\n", max_colour);

unsigned char *data = malloc(width*height);
fread(ptr,width*height,1,data);
```
````

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: Your parameters are backward.

Comment: thanks solved it! :D